# JSON Deserialize convert negative value to absolute

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJson>(input)` to parse the incoming string.

MyJson class is declared as below

```
public class MyJson
{
    public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    // some other classes
} 

public class ClassA
{ 
    public decimal? ValueA { get; set; }
    // some other values
}
```

While incoming string, `input`, has content as

```
{"ClassA":{"ValueA":"-100.11"}}
```

The parse does not throw any error and all values are parsed successfully, except the negative value -100.11 has been converted to 100.11.

Any idea on how this would happen?

Comment: What happens if your input is `{"ClassA":{"ValueA":-100.11}}`?

Comment: This is the input from third party, can't be modified. I doubt it's the potential cause but can't further prove.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Here's a Fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/aSBJni).

Comment: Can't reproduce.  See the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9lu3JS

Comment: Works fine for me too. This could have something to do with culture-specific parsing behavior.

Comment: Think you are all right, I've placed the complete code in fiddle and it gives correct result. The same code just gives me different data dump in my local. Could be configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify `CultureInfo` for deserialization:

```
var json = "{ \"ClassA\":{ \"ValueA\":\"-100.11\"} }";
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Culture = new CultureInfo("en")
};
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJson>(json, settings);
```